# Restore a front load washing machine door boot

Tags: appliances

I have a front load Samsung washing machine, and it's started leaking around the door, which I take to mean that the seal is getting warn out.
Is there any possible way to get it working again, or is just replacing it the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to restore resiliency and surface integrity to that type of material for a substantial length of time. The seal itself shouldn't be terribly expensive, and replacement is the best long-term fix.

Comment: Yeah, I just ordered a new one. It was just $60 I wasn't hoping to spend right now :)

Comment: @AndyD273 I had replaced ours some years back. Keep your old one to compare to the new one. I had ordered a replacement and the replacement was very floppy and light weight. I returned it for another which more closely matched the original in stoutness. The replacement has already held up a few years thus far.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is of course to replace the seal.  The temporary fix is a squirt of silicone lubricant spray, which can make it more pliable and seal better, for a short time.  Same goes for windshield wipers.

Comment: I'll have to pick some of that up so we can get some stuff washed until the new seal gets delivered. Thanks for the tip.